# Why do I need dbus?

Tags: linux, process, d-bus

I recently removed dbus from my system (along with consolekit and polkit). I didn't notice any change (I was running it as system daemon and per-user from .xinitrc). However, many people claim that one just need dbus, most of linux applications are using it etc etc.
My question is, why do I need it? I don't think I understand what does it exactly do. I know that is a "message bus system", that processes communicate through it etc. And? I still don't know what do I gain from using it. Could someone explain it to me, preferably with examples "from real life"?

Comment: Don't worry, you won't even need to install/uninstall dbus in the near future. It is part of the kernel now: http://kroah.com/log/blog/2014/01/15/kdbus-details/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an end-user, you don't. There is nothing that D-Bus does that couldn't be done a different way.

The benefits of D-Bus are primarily of interest to developers. It unifies several tricky bits of functionality (object-oriented and type-safe messaging, daemon activation, event notification, transport independence) under a single facility that works the same regardless of what programming language or windowing toolkit is in use.

Comment: But shouldnt then some application not bei able to run if dbus is not present?

Comment: Some, sure. But it is possible to make it an optional requirement regardless.

Comment: System tray notifications on DEs are created by sending DBUS messages. At least I had one setup that used DBUS on awesome for that reason.

Comment: @Spidey: Yes, but there's no reason that they couldn't use domain sockets for that. It just so happens that D-Bus is a better choice.

Comment: Of course, DBUS is just another IPC protocol. But this is one of the examples that the OP asked for in the first place.